# Intern client.js does not use the packages definition from the config file, so cannot resolve dojo/_base/declare

Tags: dojo, intern

I've been fighting with Intern for quite a while, to test both server code (following [these recommendations](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/node/)) and client code (tradionnal app, as defined on [this project of mine](https://github.com/DomDerrien/custom-portal/blob/master/src/main/webapp/js/dderrien/portal.js), for example).

The Intern config file contains:

```
loader: {
    packages: [
        { name: 'dojo', location: './libs/dojo' },
        { name: 'server', location: './server' }
    ]
},
```

However, the location of the dojo package is always ignored. The reported error is:

```
$ node node_modules/intern/client.js config=intern suites=server/model/tests/News
Defaulting to "console" reporter
Error: Failed to load module dojo/_base/declare from <root>/dojo/_base/declare.js (parent: server/model/Ne
ws)
    at <root>\node_modules\intern\node_modules\dojo\dojo.js:742:12
    at fs.js:207:20
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

I redacted for the <root> part to simplify the output.

My current workaround is to copy the dojo folder at the <root> level but that's inconvenient...

My current folder structure is:

```
<root>
    |- client
    |- libs
    |    |- dojo
    |    |- ...
    |- node_modules
    |    |- grunt
    |    |- intern
    |    |- ...
    |- server
         |- dao
         |    |- tests
         |- model
         |    |- tests
         |- ...
```

Where am I wrong?

**Update:** Everywhere I read (like [here](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Running-Intern)), the configuration is specified as a MID, not as a filename with an extension. When I run my command with "**config=intern.js**" the configuration is correctly processed (I've hacked "client.js" to log the config content). Note: I'm running Node.js/Intern on a Windows machine...

**Additional information:** Here is the minimum content required to process my tests.

```
define({
    loader: {
        packages: [
            { name: 'dojo', location: './libs/dojo' },
            { name: 'server', location: './server' }
        ]
    },
    suites: [ 'server/allTests' ]
});
```

Comment: Could you provide your entire config file, and also which version of Intern you’re using? What you’re describing doesn’t make a lot of sense with the defaults being what they are.

Comment: I use Intern 1.4, retreived with npm. The minimum in my intern.js is listed as part of the question above. The command line: **./node_modules/intern/bin/intern-client.js config=intern.js**.
Without the extension for the config file, my allTest series is ignored. With it, the ~30 tests are correctly processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue I faced is related to the loader:

- If the config file `intern.js` is at the root level, the command MUST contain the extension: `config=intern.js`;
- If the config file is in a subfolder like `tests` then the extension MUST be omitted in the command: `config=tests/intern`.

This happens in `intern/client.js`, line 38, with the call to the Node.js `require()` function.

Comment: It should always be the latter; `config` is a module ID, not a file path. If it is not always working as the latter it is possibly a bug in the loader but I can’t think offhand of what it might be doing.

Comment: New to intern, but this fixed it for me. I put intern.js at root level and config=intern did not register the config file, config=intern.js does.